# How to set terminal to open in the current project directory?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

Whenever I press CTRL + SHIFT + `, it opens a terminal with it's root path to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0. It wasn't happening before activating scripts on PowerShell in order to allow it to run scripts. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution. The [Terminal Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) page indicates we can use [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) in the arguments, but they don't work for me. Will update if a solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

use the cd command to navigate to the path

```
cd "path"
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code normally opens the terminal in the project directory. It does this when I open a CMD terminal for example, but for some reason it doesn't for the default terminal which is PowerShell.